# DS 160 Photo Error - US visa

Tags: usa

I'm trying to apply for a US visa from Singapore. When I get to the last step of the DS 160, where I'm required to upload my photo, I get an error saying 'An error occurred while processing your photo, please try again later'. To be clear, the photo passed all the checks in the previous stage and it says in green that the photo is ok, but on the next page it shows this error

[image: Error]

I've been trying for about 20 hours now on several computers and mobiles and different browsers. None of it seems to work. Is anyone else facing this problem now and/or has figured out a proper solution to this? I tried calling the embassy, but we were told that they could not help.

Comment: Is it possible to go back and upload a different photo?